# How to efficiently remove rows from table B, which are identical with table A

Tags: mysql

I do have a huge table **A** with N > 2m rows that should be updated periodically with data from external API service. Because table is huge and has some heavy indexes I do have a strong pressure on making as little update calls as I can.

To achieve that I am making a `TEMPORARY TABLE` **B**, where I am pushing every data I get from API service and than making an update with JOIN, to update thousands (60k > N > 50k) of rows in one operation.

Case is I am updating records even if their are identical between those two tables. My question is if there is a more efficient than following method to delete from table B rows that are identical so I won't try to update them on my call:

```
DELETE del
FROM B del
INNER JOIN A
  ON del.id=A.id
WHERE
      del.col_1 = A.col_1
  AND del.col_2 = A.col_2
  ....
```

assuming there may be more than 15 columns to name what I would like to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

hard to say, but you can try a `NATURAL JOIN` like this

```
DELETE del
FROM B del
NATURAL JOIN E
```